# SSAS cube creation question - parent/child relationship

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I'm currently struggling with the creation of a cube.

Below is a simplified version of my relational data...

**Race**

```
Id  Type  Total 
1   A     3 
2   A     2
```

**Result**

```
Id  RaceId  Gender  Position
1   1       M       2
2   1       M       3
3   1       F       1
4   2       F       2
5   2       F       1
```

In some kind of pusedo language I would like to be able to run this query:

```
SELECT Sum(Total), Sum(Position) WHERE RaceType = A AND Gender = M
```

And I would expect to get the results: 3, 5

I have tried a couple of different configurations of dimensions and measures but always end up with the answer 5, 5.

I'm sure this is possible to achieve with the cube, I just don't currently have the knowledge to figure it out - any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the structure of your cube

Comment: Happy to do so - just a bit green with all of this - what aspects of the structure would be helpful?

Comment: Well aremy assumptions on Dimensions/Measures below sensible? If not, what dimensions/measures are present in your cube, and how are the dimensions and measures assocaited? Also what is the default aggregation of your measures (if you dont know its almost certainly SUM)

Comment: The dimensions of Race and Result are correct, however the measures are in two different measure groups as they are based on different underlying tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently being able to see the dimensions/measures present in your cube, it would be roughly

```
SELECT
{
   [Measures].[Total],
   [Measures].[Position]
}
ON 0
FROM [YourCube]
WHERE(
  [Race].[RaceType].[A],
  [Result].[Gender].[M]
)
```

This is assuming you've chosen the default aggregation for your measures, which is SUM.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I don't have access to my cube at the minute to try this so I'll ask instead... if I were to change Race 2 to type B and Result 4 to have a Gender of M would this still return the same results - it's this that I have struggled with.

Comment: @Big Fat Noodle - I dont think so, as result 4 would be Gender M but not RaceType A. The criteria in the WHERE for MDX can be roughly thought of as an AND operation.

Comment: OK, so is this because of the way that the dimensions and/or underlying data is structured, or is it just not possible to solve?